# Protractor does not runnnig correctly as Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, angular, protractor

I'm trying to run my Protractor test on a Jenkins server. But I get every time following error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'visibilityOf' of undefined
>
> > Stacktrace:
> > TypeError: Cannot read property 'visibilityOf' of undefined at waitingForElement
> > (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/workspace/project/dist/dev/scripts/test/e2e/helper.e2e.js:9:20)
> > at Object.switchTab (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/workspace/project/dist/dev/scripts/test/e2e/helper.e2e.js:135:5)
> > at null.
> > (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/workspace/project/dist/dev/scripts/test/e2e/test-employee.e2e.js:87

This is the respective code:

```
function waitingForElement(elem, timeOut) { 
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(elem), timeOut);
    ....    
}
```

And at the top line line I have a reference to the angular-protractor typings:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../typings_custom/angular-protractor/index.d.ts" />
```

And this is my Jenkins configuration:

```
echo "build tests"
npm run build.e2e   
#Run protractor
protractor protractor-config.js --params.url "http://localhost:90" --suite testSuite
```

But when I'm runnig the Protractor test locally or in a server terminal then they are working, but not as Jenkins job.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the lines from the test that is using the `waitingForElement` that is failing? From the error message, it appears that the `elem` argument that you are passing in is `undefined`

Comment: Solved - The error results out of missing rights. I have been tried to use the gobal installation of protractor, but i need to use the local protractor installation (./node_modules/protractor/...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error results in missing rights to execute the global protractor installation.

The solution is quite simple, I need to use the local "installation"
of protractor:
`./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor ...`